# Highlight specific parts of a mesh c++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have imported a mesh object (.obj file from blender) into openGl window (glfw) context. I am following various tutorials on 3D picking to allow me to select it. What I cannot get my head around is, how to allow sub-portions of the mesh to get highlighted when clicked at one point. For example, a car mesh in which if you click over the door, the entire door gets highlighted. Without going into game engines, because my intention is to apply this concept to 3d diagrams in an app, what is the most straightforward way to implement this.

PS -- Before someone downvotes this, I have spent hours on google trying to search for an answer so apologies if this is off-topic / unsuitable.

Comment: Is this a single mesh, or are you dealing with multiple meshes that represent the different parts of the car (door, etc.)? Post your vertex and fragment shader source if possible.

Comment: If you created a car in parts with Objects such as: door, mirror, roof, tires etc. Then you could implement a function within the class Object example,  door Object that responds to the mouse click and execute functionality such as: paint, color or open door functions.

Comment: I think i will import several objects corresponding to the different selectable parts of the main mesh and then take it from there thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the mesh has some colour information in form of vertex colours or textures. To highlight part of the mesh, you need to change the colour information from vertex arrays or textures that are used. This can be expensive cpu operation to generate the required arrays and textures, but after the data is generated, blitting it to screen takes no time. The main complexity is in modifying the data structures of the mesh.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to send the color as a uniform to the shader for just that mesh? Then you don't have to modify anything on the CPU.